# Vba range object single column autofill

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to autofill a single column of range object. Eventually I want to autofill using a formula.
I was trying this on a toy example below.
This causes a type mismatch error which I cant seem to figure out.

```
Sub Macro1()
    
    Dim wk As Worksheet
    
    Set wk = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
    
    wk.Cells.Clear
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = wk.Range("A1:B5")
    
    rng.rows(1).Columns(1) = 1
    
    rng.rows(1).Columns(1).Select
    
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=rng(1 & ":" & rng.rows.Count, "A")
    
End Sub
```

A vba newbie here, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A1:A5, trying to autofill the first column of the selected two column range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer to the first column of `rng`. Change

```
rng.rows(1).Columns(1) = 1

rng.rows(1).Columns(1).Select
    
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=rng(1 & ":" & rng.rows.Count, "A")
```

to

```
With rng
    .Cells(1).Value = 1
    .Cells(1).AutoFill Destination:=.Columns(1)
End With
```

If you want to autofill from row 3 onwards:

```
With rng.Columns(1).Cells(3)
    .Value = 1
    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 2)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works. If say I wanted to only autofill only row 3 onwards. How would I modify it?

Comment: @Thedudeabides - added a code snippet.